# wp7: how do I check to see if my collection exists?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an ObservableCollection collection : historyItemCollection

I populate this collection when history is needed.  I'm running into an error where the collection doesn't yet exist (i.e. no history).

I'm getting a NULL reference error when I try to do a count on this collection or reference it in ANY way....

What is the best way for me to check to see if this collection exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (historyItemCollection == null)` should do the trick.

You can initialize it during the constructor with `historyItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<item>()` then do the check like this:

`if (historyItemCollection.Count() == 0)`

Comment: @johnforrest - Thanks.  Worked like a champ.